# How can I send JSON with ExpressJS as UTF-8?

Tags: javascript, json, express, encoding, utf-8

I've been struggling with a new web app I'm making. In previous situations I cannot recall to have encountered this issue. I'm testing with a very simple piece of code.

```
var jsonToSend = {hello: "woørld"};
app.get('/someUrl', function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(jsonToSend);
}
```

Output is: `{"hello":"Woørld"}` with `Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8` in the network tab. I also tried various attempts with `JSON.stringify` and adding `charset` to `setHeader`, though it seems to be right in the network tab. How can I make sure the data is correctly encoded from the server?

I use WebStorm and I checked file encoding to be `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the issue had to be towards my IDE. So this answer would target those of you who are using WebStorm:

I had previously started a project on my windows computer which converted my source files to windows-1252 encoding instead of utf-8. Make sure to do `Preferences > File Encoding` and set all encoding to UTF-8 and convert old files. The file encoding is also marked in the settings view.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `res.set({ 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });`:

```
var jsonToSend = {"\"hello"\": "\"woørld"\"};
app.get('/someUrl', function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  res.set({ 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });

  res.send(jsonToSend);
}
```

Comment: Still seems to have the correct Content-Type with this, though it should be automatic with json. Still wont encode the Norwegian letters.